# Which Targaryen woman foresaw the doom of Valyria?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the beginning of *"Game of Thrones Conquest & Rebellion"* (animated series) while talking about the Targaryens, Viserys narrates:

> Twelve years before the Doom, despite the sneers of his rivals, Aenar Targaryen abandoned the capital with his family. Legends claim that his daughter foresaw the destruction of the city in a dream.

Because of the premonition in her dream, the Targaryens are the last of the Valyrians who escape (are exiled) and survive.

My question is, who is that Targaryen?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Targaryen girl who foresaw the Doom was [Daenys the Dreamer](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Daenys_Targaryen).

However the video, as you described (I haven't watched it), appears to be wrong when they say Targaryens were the last (As in only) Valyrians who escaped the doom.

Targaryens were one of the forty Freeholder families of Valyria all of whom had dragons. When Daenys had a dream about destruction of Valyria, Targaryens did not flee alone. There already were Valyrian Houses [Celtigar](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Celtigar) and [Velaryon](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Velaryon) in the Narrow Sea Isles. Targaryens made Dragonstone their seat while Velaryons settled in Driftmark and Celtigars settled in Claw Isle.

You might find it interesting, While Targaryens lost their possessions after Robert's Rebellion, Velaryons and Celtigars still held theirs. Lord Monford Velaryon was a key vassal of Stannis Baratheon and died fighting for him during Battle of Blackwater bay. His half Brother Aurane Waters fought for Stannis too but changed sides after he was taken PoW and rose to the position of Tommen's Master of Ships. Lord Ardrian Celtigar also fought for Stannis in the battle but changed sides after he was taken PoW.

Furthermore, there was a sizable population of Valyrians in the colonies of Lys, Volantis, Myr, Norvos, Qohor, Lorath, Pentos and Tyrosh. Valyrian blood still runs strong in the [Old-Blood of Volantis](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Old_Blood) and [Lys](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Lys#People).

We can't even say that Targaryens were the last Dragonriders who escaped the Doom. Emperor [Aurion](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aurion), self proclaimed Emperor of Valyria, was a Dragonrider and was in Qohor when the Doom fell. He proclaimed himself the Emperor, raised an army of 30,000 Qohoriks and went to reclaim Valyria with his dragon but he and his army disappeared during their quest. That event made Targaryens the last Dragonlords in the world.

So in conclusion:

1. Daenys the Dreamer is the woman in question.
2. Targaryens were not the last Valyrians.
3. Targaryens were not the last Dragonlords.

Comment: thank you  ! this is brilliant. And is all information from the books ?

Comment: @Anu7 It is. In the main series it is scattered all across the five books but with the release of TWOIAF, it has been compiled into one.

Comment: oh great to know ! i just started SOIAF.

Comment: @Anu7 Welcome Aboard, If you have any questions WRT books while you read, we would be glad to have you over at [Scifi and Fantasy SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com)